# How can I use the reactjs library in java application?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, d3.js, nashorn

I would like to use the react-d3-library in java application.
I already integrated the javascript in java application by using Nashorn.
But I could not find the solution how to integrate with reactjs.

this is my integrating with javascript code.

```
    ...

        ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        engine.eval(new FileReader("res/test.js"));
        Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
        Object result = invocable.invokeFunction("fun2", "BarChart");

    ...
```

How can I use the reactjs module like above code?
Help me. Thanks.

Comment: Nashorn is going away, and using React from a server-side application is somewhat unusual. You should explain what your overall goals are.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am going to draw the chart on java application by with d3js library. what is important that I should get the svg file from this application.

Comment: Do you have any other problem for this?